# Import data into SQL Server from an Excel file

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have an Excel (version 2007) file which has more than 700 columns and I need to import that data into my SQL Server database. When I import the data, it only imports the first 255 columns as columns in table that is created by SQL Server. I want to know how to import all 700 columns.

Comment: Do you mean 700 columns or 700 rows?

Comment: 700 columns not rows

Comment: Don't you think it might be quite important to mention how you are importing it...

Comment: hi @BurakKarakuş i have 700 header columns

Comment: @JamesZ from sql server right click on database name go to task than go to import data than select data source i.e excel file and import it in my database

Comment: Did you try using DTS's excel import feature? What method did you use?

Comment: @BurakKarakuş yes i used DTS

Comment: @BurakKarakuş basically DTS only select first 255 columns and that table is created by DTS only show 255 columns is there is a way to import my all columns in my database.

Comment: @BurakKarakuş thanks for your suggestion i am going to trying this than i will update you

Comment: @BurakKarakuş hi you are awesome man thanks to save my life and its realy works!

Comment: I'm glad that it worked. :) but can you say that which of the solutions worked under my answer to help the other people who might have the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try saving the excel data file as a text delimited file, then choose "flat file" in DTS. That should solve your problem.

Here is another solution to the problem as well: https://waheedrous.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/ssis-importing-an-excel-file-with-over-255-columns/